# Compatibility issues with .NET 4.8, .netstandard2.0 and .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, .net-4.8, .net-standard-2.0

I created a new application in .NET 6. The real engine is written in .NET 4.8 and I can't change it now, so the layer on .NET 6 that is really call the engine in .NET 4.8 is written in .netstandard2.0.

Mainly the problems I see is the compatibility of dll (dll hell!). The engine is referenced by the new application in the same directory `net6.0` and try to call the dll made for .NET 6.0 / .netstandard.20, it's dangerous because the dll couldn't have the same method of .NET  4.8.

For example I have read many topics about this one

> Method not found: 'System.String System.AppDomainSetup.get_PrivateBinPath()'

I can't really understand why. I explain better: the .NET 4.8 project has this problem, the new solution is made in .NET 6, calling the engine in .NET 4.8 trough .netstandard2.0 ... if .NET 4.8 works fine in the legacy solution why when it's called from the new solution in .net6 use a different dll and make this mess?

These kind of issues make developing new application struggling

I tried to fix many times, changing the code, find another solutions and dll but sometimes it's impossible to have a compatibility

Comment: A .net6.0 project runs on CoreCLR and gets its basic types like System.String from System.Private.CoreLib.dll.  There is *some* support for using .net4.x assemblies.  When such an assembly asks for System.String from mscorlib.dll then the CLR redirects it to System.Private.CoreLib.dll.  Nice, lots of legacy assemblies still work.  But that ends at the AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath, there is nothing to redirect to.  AppDomain support was removed in .netcore, AppDomainSetup has only two properties left (ApplicationBase and TargetFrameworkName).  So the exception is entirely normal.

Comment: @HansPassant ok, I got it, this is an example and I still can't figure out why .net4.8 project cant' call the correct CLR for itself. I can't change old the legacy codebase to run the new application

Comment: There can be only one version of the CLR, when you target .net6 then that's always CoreCLR.

Comment: the way you explain what you doing is quite confusing. 
You have two apps that share a common Dll 2.0 standard and you saying you have an issue?

Comment: The following may be of interest: [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0),  [Analyze your dependencies to port code from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/third-party-deps#net-framework-compatibility-mode), and [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)